# "Site has not yet been deployed" after netlify deployment

Tags: deployment, netlify

I already tried a million times and not able to figure out where I am going wrong. I tried simple static website repo. I even added `parcel` bundler. I just get same error message.

I even forked `netlify`'s own demo repo. And I got same message. Why I am not able to deploy the site?

[image]

I looked at forums, blogs and even answer in this forum and I am not finding clue to this exact message. I didn't have `netlify.toml` file. I added that file too and I don't see any change in deployment status.

---

Initially I was trying to just create site online by connecting to GitHub repo. When I tried `Netlify-CLI` I could see some deploy action happen. But server was not render. Found a guide here: https://github.com/Tanu-N-Prabhu/Multiplication-Table-App

Followed last 3 steps under Deployment section:

- Go to your Netlify Dashboard to the project. Click on Site has not yet been Deployed. Again click on Deploy Preview this will unlock the `Preview Deploy` which is a temporary URL.
- After viewing the Preview, click on Publish deploy option to deploy your project.
- Now your project is live and deployed on the internet.

These steps worked. But Javascript files were not rendering. I wonder why the whole process is so cumbersome when they advertise everything is taken care by Netlify automatically? There is no document for `Site has not yet been deployed` on their site and google search only leads me to `Page not found` forum page.

Answer (score 1):

You must add the `--prod`.
The command should look like this: `netlify deploy --prod`.
This fixed it for me.